# Read SharePoint List in either ASP.Net or WinForm Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, winforms

I am looking for a good sample code to retrieve a SharePoint List.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/77942/SharePoint-Reading-values-from-items-in-a-list) Code Project as example. You will need to import [Microsoft.SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.aspx) namespace.